# NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! Angular 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I, am using the Angular template in visual studio 2017. Then I updated to angular 5.2. I, tried to find the solution. But didn't got exact solution.

The service class is calling the http call.However I, am getting an error as

[image: error message]

Service.TS

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginViewModel as loginVM } from "../../viewmodel/app.viewmodel"
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private loginUrl = "Account/Authentication";
    private _httpClientModule: HttpClient;
    constructor(httpClientModule: HttpClient) {
        this._httpClientModule = httpClientModule;
    }

    public LoginHttpCall(_loginVM: loginVM) {

        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        this._httpClientModule.post(this.loginUrl, _loginVM, { headers }).
            subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
            },
            err => {
                console.log("Error occured.");
            });
    }

}
```

Here is my Component class

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from "../app/app.component";
import { LoginService } from "../../service/account/app.service.account.login";
import { LoginViewModel } from "../../viewmodel/app.viewmodel";
declare var componentHandler: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [LoginViewModel, LoginService]
})
export class LoginComponent {
    private _appComponent: AppComponent;
    private _loginService: LoginService;
    constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent, loginService: LoginService) {
        this._appComponent = appComponent;
        this._appComponent.menulist = false;
        this._loginService = loginService;
    }
}
```

app.shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { MobileComponent } from './components/mobile/mobile.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        MobileComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'mobile', component: MobileComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

I, don't know where I, am doing mistake. Since I , am new in angular. I tried to add HttpClient under @NgModule but gives some other error . Since As per my knowledge I don't need to add in app.shared.module.ts file. Since HttpClient is used in service and component level.

Can anyone please tell me where I, am doing wrong .

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`HttpClient` needs for the module `HttpClientModule` instead of `HttpModule` to be imported and added in the imports of the module.

For more see [**Documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/http)

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        HttpClientModule,
        ...
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared { }
```

Comment: @RajeevRanjan Thanks. Updated

Comment: Thank you! It is working for me I have imort import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; in app.module.ts and updated   imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,HttpClientModule],
with the HttpClientModule. and now the service imprted http is working.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved this annoying issue after struggling much hussle.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm clear cache 
npm update 
rm -rf /node_modules
npm i --save
```

Then import same module into app root module.
Hope it works for you.